# What set do these LEGO parts belong to? Star Wars-type patterns, Bionicle connectors

Tags: set-identification

Please help identify these Lego sets:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not one set. You have at least one Star Wars set, one Bionicle set, and a lot of very generic pieces. Are you interested in where a specific piece might have come from?

Comment: Yes. Please I want the sets first. Son got it for his cousin and we don't have idea where to get the instructions. Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

The round grey printed discs, the tan gears, the grey worm screw, the boat studs and the black rope in the first photo, the 6x4 and 6x12 grey plates from the third and fourth photo are found together in [10178: Motorised Walking AT-AT](https://brickset.com/sets/10178-1/Motorised-Walking-AT-AT): [image] *(Thanks to Chronocidal for the additional info)*

---

The blue sloped piece with the hexagonal sticker motif in the second photo could be from [7667: Imperial Dropship](https://brickset.com/sets/7667-1/Imperial-Dropship):
[image]

---

The white Bionicle pieces on the third photo are definitely from [8747: Visorak Suukorak](https://brickset.com/sets/8747-1/Visorak-Suukorak):
[image]

I believe the rest of the pieces are way too generic and could have come from many different sets, but somebody will definitely correct me if I'm wrong.

---

There are a few non-LEGO pieces as well:

[image]
And
[image]

Comment: The mostly-smooth plates in OP's fourth picture exist in the AT-AT set (as the side panels on the body), but not in the AT-TE set.  Same with the khaki gears in the first picture.

Comment: Just as an (obvious) comment: the fact that certain parts come from the above sets does NOT mean the complete set is in that bag of parts. Based on what I see I think none of these sets are there, you just have a random bag of parts.

Comment: Thank your so much for your input!

Comment: @Angel You are welcome, feel free to accept the answer if you believe this to be satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely parts of the motorised walking AT-AT, rather than the clone wars walker, other than that I agree with the above.

Comment: Thank you for the input Lex, could you please elaborate a bit on your answer? The reasoning behind your conclusion would make a huge difference to the value of this contribution.